# Symbols (storing strings in variables vs symbols)

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

I saw that `object_id` of strings is always different whereas symbols' `object_id` is the same (if the value is equal). As I understand, the difference between symbols and strings is immutability and performance. Can't we just store a string inside a variable and freeze it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] can't we just store a string inside a variable and freeze it?

Almost, recent versions of Ruby can optimize frozen strings:

```
'foo'.freeze.object_id #=> 70313275108080
'foo'.freeze.object_id #=> 70313275108080
```

But this optimization is limited. It works for string *literals* (as shown above), but it doesn't work if the string is frozen later on:

```
a = 'foo'
a.freeze
a.object_id #=> 70313275335500

b = 'foo'
b.freeze
b.object_id #=> 70313275274260
```

Unless you enable the `frozen_string_literal` feature:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

puts 'foo'.object_id
puts 'foo'.object_id
```

Output:

```
$ ruby test.rb
70185151269500
70185151269500
```

Or, from the command line:

```
$ ruby --enable-frozen-string-literal -e "puts 'foo'.object_id, 'foo'.object_id"
70102955495340
70102955495340
```

Comment: So where to use Strings and where to use Symbols then?

Comment: @RamziddinMakhmudov use a string if its content is important, i.e. the characters. If you want an identifier or a label, use a symbol.

Comment: Thank you for clean and understandable answer =)

Comment: BTW, the frozen string optimization is an optimization for strings. It's not meant as a replacement for symbols.

Comment: Thank you for helping, Stefan! I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

`freeze` prevents modification of the actual object, however variable are references to objects so you can still change the reference.  The following for example is perfectly valid.

```
a = "foo"
a.freeze
a = "boo"
```

At the end of this `a` is equal to "boo".

In Ruby versions 2.1 and older a symbol is assigned an available `object_id` and any time the same symbol identifier is used the same object_id will always be used; this is never garbage collected.  This is immutable, but it is also more efficient (less memory overhead).

In Ruby versions 2.2 and above the behavior is basically the same, except symbols can be garbage collected. The reason for this change was to prevent a symbol DoS attack.

Comment: So where to use Strings and where to use Symbols then?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll read about symbol DoS attack :)